# Android Project Upgrade - Issue with gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have to upgrade old android project.
I have done some changes to build.gradle file as below :

**build.gradle file**:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'io.fabric'
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
//apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdk 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.brian.skyazul"
        minSdk 30
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"

        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }



        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
//    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'

    implementation files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    }
```

Currently, Getting below error :

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'skyazul-android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find any version that matches com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0+.
> Versions that do not match:
> - 2.5.0-alpha-preview-02
> - 2.5.0-alpha-preview-01
> - 2.4.0-alpha7
> - 2.4.0-alpha6
> - 2.4.0-alpha5
> - + 145 more
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
> Required by:
> project :
>
> Possible solution:
>
> - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Can anyone guide me?

**Edit :**
build.gradle (project level)

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change this in your build.gradle(Module)

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }

}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Add this in your build.gradle(Project)

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        }
    }
apply plugin: 'java'
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }
    }
```

Comment: the project is in java

Comment: now it saying :
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'io.fabric'] was not found in any of the following sources:

Comment: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_a9y8tw3e5o7pt7hhg1m9q3anu$_run_closure2@6e9c5d11] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: are you sure you are using the build.gradle in project and not module?

Comment: I have added EDIT section for project level build.gradle file.

Comment: Hey bro I am now getting  : 
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

Answer (score 1):

Define the `repositories` in `settings.gradle`:

```
import org.gradle.api.initialization.resolve.RepositoriesMode

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

include ':app'
```

Then the `build.gradle` can set up these plugins:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        agp_version = '7.2.1' // eg. matching Android Studio Chipmunk Patch 1
        gms_version = '4.3.13'
        kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
        crashlytics_version = '2.8.1'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version "$agp_version" apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version "$agp_version" apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version "$kotlin_version" apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version "$gms_version" apply false
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version "$crashlytics_version" apply false
}
```

There is no `jcenter()` and do not mix `com.android.support` with `androidx` libraries; which means that package `com.android.support:cardview-v7` needs to be replaced altogether, also in XML and code. And replace `com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics`; Fabric Crashlytics is now Firebase Crashlytics. `targetSdk 32` means `compileSdk 32` and `JavaVersion.VERSION_11`. While being unable to set `android.enableJetifier=false`, you might still have a dependency issue, even if it may build.

---

And I'd suggest to better ignore all `alpha` and `beta` packages with a `lint.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="GradleDependency">
        <ignore regexp="is available: .*alpha|beta"/>
    </issue>
</lint>
```

Comment: so I need to remove all the fabric related code to firebase crashlytics. correct?

Comment: Can you please tell me, Which gradle version do I need to use ?

Comment: It now saying : > Could not find method android() for arguments

Comment: Those Java dependencies are a mess and hopelessly outdated. "Could not find method android() for arguments" usually means that you've managed to produce a syntax error in the `android` block.

Comment: Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
Your current JDK is located in  /home/jaiminmodi/.jdks/corretto-1.8.0_292/jre
You can try some of the following options:
  - changing the IDE settings.
  - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
  - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
Gradle settings

Comment: Now, I am getting : 
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.